# Does domain suffix affect SEO?

Tags: seo, domains, search-engines, url

my first question here! I have a question regarding URL suffixes. Say I have a company, let's call it `example-it`. If I then purchase the domain `www.example.it`, thus incorporating the company name into the domain would this affect how it is ranked in Google? And what version of Google this is displayed in?

So for example would a search engine "assume" that this is an Italian domain and give it less precedence when searched for from `.co.uk` or`.com` search engines? Or is SEO driven solely on content?

Any help would be much appreciated and if you need more info please let me know.

Comment: Also for the `example-it` domain question check out http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/45465/is-it-a-bad-idea-to-use-a-domain-hack-for-my-personal-website-name/45466#45466

Comment: @bybe thanks! I did try a search but I obviously didn't search the correct terminology.